# Generating accounts with pyethereum is insanely slow

Tags: dapp-development, accounts, pyethereum, pyethapp

I'm trying to debug an app that at some point needs to create a password 
protected account. When I reach that point in my code using pycharm's debugger it takes forever to generate an account protected by a four character password.

The code is:

```
new_account = accounts.Account.new(password, priv_key, path)
```

where all fields are not **None**. Is there a way to debug faster?

Comment: Have you tried other clients? geth, parity?

Comment: I'm limited to using pyethapp because at the moment it is the only client supporting programmable hooks (I need to make a syscall once a transaction has been confirmed)

Comment: @Sebi: What platform/OS are you running on?

Comment: @jimkberry Debian 8.3, Jessie, x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Account generation is slow by design.

Part of the account generation process involves `scrypt` or `pbkdf2`, password hashing algorithms that are designed to be *slow* in order to mitigate brute force attacks on your private keys.

If you look [here in the pyethereum source](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/5a0c9f4d8f12fe60b2c5007233327eccf2cd7018/ethereum/keys.py#L35) you can see the parameters that are used for each of these hash functions.  Both use a work factor/iteration count of `262114` or `2**18` which should translate to something between 1-3 seconds of hashing depending on how old your hardware is.

Comment: In python it's more like 3 or 4 minutes, perhaps even more. Even so, once an attacker has your account only strong (60+ random & non-ASCII character) passwords will keep it safe, regardless of the hashing algorithms involved (at least in practical scenarios). This approach is uselessly slow, at least in my opinion.

Comment: Have you profiled the code and why it's so slow.  I suspect that the slowness of the hashing algorithms isn't what your seeing but rather something different.  Possibly your IDE is doing something that's adding significant overhead to the process?

Comment: Yes, too many rounds of hmac-sha256. I've run it both inside the IDE (pycharm) and also, separately, from bash. The latter is faster but not by much (at least 2 or 3 minutes per account generation).

Comment: can you try this code and see how long it takes?  `from ethereum import keys; keys.make_keystore_json(keys.sha3('cow'), 'abcd')`.  I'm seeing 22 second generation times.

Comment: It take ~4 minutes per run. I have rebuild pyethereum and decreased the constant 1000 times.

Comment: Do you happen to be on a really old or slow machine?  That's quite odd.

Comment: No, it's a gaming laptop.